# we have site running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server 14.04 Magento 1.9.2.2 Https issues

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, magento, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

we have site running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server 14.04 Magento 1.9.2.2 
http://dragonstore.com already configured for https but not redirecting automatically on https://www.dragonstore.com

This issues i am facing 
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at dragonstore.com Port 80

How to resolve this issues any solution

Comment: This question is currently too broad to answer. How are you terminating your SSL? At the web server on your EC2 instance? Or are you using a load balancer and offloading your SSL?

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect **HTTP** request to **HTTPS** using below htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

for more reference you can read this site [Click Here](https://in.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828)

Comment: i have inserted this code on my .htacess but its not working same error is showing.

Comment: can you please update your htaccess file? and make sure your server should allow htaccess file by default in EC2 server it not allow.

Comment: how can i enable .htacess file in EC2 server because first time i am using Amazon web hosting is there any easy way we can Enable this .htacess file this server

Comment: you can use this tutorial for enable htaccess in your server [how to enable htaccess in ubuntu server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: still my website is not working i have tried  any solution please.

Comment: This is only solution. no any other solution.